# CAST Date and Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my Data Table I have a Date Column Format = `yyyy/mm/dd` and a Time column Format `hh:mm:ss`. I am trying to concat the two so I can use it in a calendar. I keep getting an error. Here is my qry: 
`CAST(T0.[Date]) AS Date) + CAST(T0.[Time]) AS Time(7))`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I just realized that the time table format is not hh:mm:ss but the values look like this: 8:43, 13:16 etc. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the bracket near the [date] and [Time]

```
CAST(T0.[Date]) AS Date) + CAST(T0.[Time]) AS Time(7))
```

change to:

```
CAST(T0.[Date] AS Date) + CAST(T0.[Time] AS Time(7))
```

**UPDATED:**
The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.

```
select cast(CAST(T0.[Date] AS date)as nvarchar(8)) + cast(CAST(T0.[Time] AS time(7)) as nvarchar(8))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CAST(T0.[Date] AS SmallDateTime) + CAST(T0.[Time] AS Time)
```

Answer (score 2):

The conversion error may be a formatting error.  Use `convert` explicitly with a format:

```
select convert(datetime, t0.[DATE], 111) + CAST(T0.[Time]) AS Time)
```

There is the possibility that some strings do not match the format that you think they have.